# Calorie timing with workouts

Tags: weightlifting, muscle, body-fat

When it comes to gaining, I usually go for a 3500 calorie a day diet, work out four times a week and end up gaining weight as both muscle and fat.

I’m working on a plan to calculate my macros more strictly so my gains are leaner, but I’m curious if the timing of nutrient consumption has an effect on the muscle vs fat gains.

Should I be eating less carbs / more protein on the days that I’m not working out to prevent fat storage? Or does eating a uniform diet across the week still allow me to accomplish the desired result, regardless of which days I actually train?

Comment: This is highly complex and small variations will likely not matter. Please remember that food, depending upon what food, will not be digested instantly but take a couple of days to be absorbed to the best if your bodies ability. I hope you realize why this delay makes your task almost impossible. However, if you manage to fine tune it and you gain 1 g fat less per month or so, well done. That only makes sense if you compete. Is that the case? If you are competitive or make a living with your body, this changes potential answers because you don't need half baked amateur advice then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes.  We think calorie timing affects muscle vs fat gain. But the questions of how much it affects it is more important.

[Mike Israetel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoKlyYzK5n0) 
 mentions that for most of us the amount of calories is much more important,for us hobby builders.

In contradiction [this study](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEbWdoceH-A) (3:20) suggested fasted cardio is not really beneficial.

My personal opinion is do what makes you feel better. Eating before and hitting the gym 4 times a week is better than pre-fasting and hitting it 1'ce a week.